# Web application utility class

Tags: java, spring, jsf, annotations, utility

The following is a utility class that is called by a LoginBean to add and get a User object from a session through FacesContext.

The application uses Spring. Should I use an annotation or is it an accepted practise to have static methods in this sort of class? If an annotation is advised, should I use @Component or @Service?

```
// Annotate as Service/Component?
public class WebUtils {

// Add user object to session
public void setUser( User user ){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put( "user", user );
}

// Get user from session
public User getUser( FacesContext context ){
    if( context != null )
        return (User) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("user");

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Nothing of all. This is the wrong approach. If you want to have something in session scope, just use a session scoped bean. See Roman's answer for the right way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment BalusC. I wish there was a site that grouped best practises :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to create separate spring bean in session scope for your purposes.

You can call it `UserSupport` or `UserController`. This bean should have methods `getUser ()`, `setUser ()` and maybe some methods which make calls to your service layer.

Comment: Or `UserManager`. The other useful methods being `login()`, `logout()` and `isLoggedin()`.

Answer (score 1):

I like to have things like this as a Spring Bean so I can inject whatever I need on it.

Then again, if a static method works for you now, you can always make it a bean later when it is required.